# git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, environment-variables

my computer shows this on intelij

```
PS C:\place for Intellij IDEA files\src\WIX1002> git
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

but i already add `git\cmd` and `bin` to environment path.  Any solution?

Comment: Can you run it using the full path?

Comment: if you check the path from inside that console ... do you see the git dir listed?

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate helps you resolve the problem. If not, please ask a _new_ question, in which you provide details about what you have tried.